# Xamarin App - Resource file, how to include an audio file into the AppResources.Designer.cs

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization, resources

I am working on a Xamarin Form App and we use .resx files for the localizations.

I have got a problem where to my Resources folder I would like to add an audio file called Beep.wav.

Previously in the AppResources.Designer.cs I used to have something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized resource of type System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream similar to System.IO.MemoryStream.
    /// </summary>
    internal static System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream Beep
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceManager.GetStream("Beep", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

but for some reason is not there anymore and when I regenerate that file by adding/removing a string in AppResources.resx file, still it is not there. It does work if I add that manually but everytime we add a new string it gets wiped away.

I am adding some screenshots to give a bit better meaning to what I am trying to achieve:

My resources folder:

[image]

My .csproj file for that project

[image]

My AppResources.Designer.cs file which should include the piece of code I have typed earlier

[image]

How do I get my Beep.wav file included in there?

This is where it is failing as it cannot find "Beep"

```
private static readonly ISimpleAudioPlayer _beepPlayer;

    static MediaPlayerHelper()
    {
        _beepPlayer = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        _beepPlayer.Load(Resources.AppResources.Beep); <--Error
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it help if you delete from .csproj the ItemGroup with `Remove` in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the .resx file, change `Strings` to `Audio`.

[image]

Click `Add Resource` to add the .wav file.

[image]

After that, it would generate the code below in `AppResources.Designer.cs`.

```
 /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized resource of type System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream similar to System.IO.MemoryStream.
    /// </summary>
    internal static System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream WAV_1MG {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetStream("WAV_1MG", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```